# Series with negative indexes

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Recall the well known theorem:

**Theorem**. Consider a series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} g_k$ of functions on a set $S\subset\Bbb R.$ Suppose that each $g_k$ is continuous on $S$ and that the series converges uniformly on $S.$ Then the series  $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} g_k$ represents a continuous function on $S.$

> Is it correct even if we replace $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} g_k$ by $\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z} g_k$ in the Theorem above?

Actually, I brought this theorem as just an example but I can make it more general. Once a fact holds for the series with positive Indexes does it hold for all integers?

Comment: I think it holds, but you don't need negative indexes. That theorem holds for sets sets of functions $f_k$ as well, supposing they all satisfy the continuity criteria and such. So adding two series should yield the same result as adding one series with negative indexes. That could change if the $g_k$ are dependent on $k$.

Comment: @TurlocTheRed, if I understood correctly this hold for countable set then the theorem for countable set of functions that satisfies the conditions. If this the case, how about uncountable set of continuous function

Comment: @Gob What is your definition of such a function series?

Comment: @ I added an answer

Answer (score 0):

If the $\sum _{k} g_k$ satisfies the hypothesis of the above theorem then the conclusion holds. The argument is the same as for original theorem.